# Julia1.0.2のフーリエ変換について

Tags: julia

基礎的な部分ですいません、似たような質問になってしまうのですが、フーリエ変換についてもどのパッケージが必要か検索してもヒットせず、ネットの方はサラッと使うだけしか書いてないのですが、

```
plan_fft(1次元配列)またはfft(１次元配列)
```

を使うにしても、どちらともnot definedとしかでないのですが、、、。
Juliaの情報が少ない分ここで質問しようと思います。
どなたか教えていただけると非常に助かります。

Comment: おそらく、[AbstractFFTs.jl](https://juliamath.github.io/AbstractFFTs.jl/stable/index.html)のインストールが必要なのではないかと思います。具体的には、`using Pkg` としてから `Pkg.add("AbstractFFTs")` を実行すると GitHub のリポジトリからファイルがダウンロードされてインストールされます。`fft()` や `plan_fft()` を利用する場合は、事前に `using AbstractFFTs` を実行しておきます。

Comment: いつも、ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

おそらく、[AbstractFFTs.jl](https://juliamath.github.io/AbstractFFTs.jl/stable/index.html) のインストールが必要なのではないかと思います。具体的には、`using Pkg` としてから `Pkg.add("AbstractFFTs")` を実行すると GitHub のリポジトリからファイルがダウンロードされてインストールされます。`fft()` や `plan_fft()` を利用する場合は、事前に `using AbstractFFTs` を実行しておきます。

---

*この投稿は [@metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51061/julia1-0-2%e3%81%ae%e3%83%95%e3%83%bc%e3%83%aa%e3%82%a8%e5%a4%89%e6%8f%9b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6#comment53288_51061) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*